# Javascript callback, execute code after calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following code in my document.ready

```
  technicianDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);
  assetsDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);

  if(#{@appointment.technician_id.present?}){
     $('#appointment_technician_id').val('{@appointment.technician_id}');
}
```

I only want the if statement to run after the first two functions are finished executing. I can't modify those functions and include the if statement in that code, because the function is called multiple times.

Comment: You could use [Deffered / Promises](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) ... with `when...then` ...

Comment: Have you looked at [async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/)

Answer (score 2):

A Simple solution will be, create a callback function and put your if condition in that function. Call your callback function inside the body of your uper functions like this:

```
function technicianDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id){
   //do you work here
   assetsDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);
}

function assetsDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id){
   //do you work here
   callback();
}

function callback(){
  if(#{@appointment.technician_id.present?}){
     $('#appointment_technician_id').val('{@appointment.technician_id}');
  }
}

technicianDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);
```

**Notes:** It will execute your functions in sequence. So your if condition will run in the end.

Comment: I didn't want to modify those other functions, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **jQuery** you can use:

```
function someFunctions(cbu_id) {
    technicianDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);
    assetsDropdownFromCBU(cbu_id);
}

$.when($.ajax(someFunctions(cbu_id))).then(function () {
    if(#{@appointment.technician_id.present?}){
        $('#appointment_technician_id').val('{@appointment.technician_id}');
    }
});
```